# typescript return object or array error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello i write application on Angular2 and Typescript and create service for get event. I guess what my function return array events, when i not pass arguments in function and return Object when have arguments.

But in my component lintner show error for this construction.

> this.event.length
>
> Type 'Event | Event[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.   Type
>   'Event' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.
>       Property 'length' is missing in type 'Event'.

Can i catch this error? Because i know what in this component get Array of Events

Comment: Some code of your service would be helpful to solve this.

Comment: @cyrix i solved this problem. When i execute my function and subscribe on result i use `this.events = result as Event[]` , and if execute function with argument i do  `this.event = result as Event`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). An example:

```
type MyEvent = { evtName: string }
function abc(): MyEvent[]
function abc(param): MyEvent
function abc(param?): any {
    // do the stuff
}

abc().length // ok
abc()[0].evtName // ok
abc("def").evtName // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory: an `Element | Element[]` is not an `Element[]` (the opposite is true, but that is not what you're doing). You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to narrow down the union type:

```
function isElement(value: Element | Element[]) value is Element {
    return value instanceof Element;
}

function functionWithReturn(): Element | Element[] {
    //Do something
}

function functionWithParameter(value: Element[]) {
    //Do something
}

function doWork() {
    let value = functionWithReturn();
    if (!isElement(value)) {
        functionWithParameter(value);
    }
}
```